# angular-nvd3 gives various errors saying that d3.scale is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm attempting a very basic `angular-nvd3` proof of concept to try to get a demo chart to render based on the `angular-nvd3` docs.

See the sample code at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aH83HT?p=preview)

I'm using the straight up Line Chart example but getting this error in the browser console:

```
angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property 'category20' of undefined
    at Object.nv.utils.defaultColor (nv.d3.js:987)
    at Object.nv.models.scatter (nv.d3.js:11844)
    at Object.nv.models.line (nv.d3.js:6467)
    at Object.nv.models.lineChart (nv.d3.js:6696)
    at Object.scope.api.updateWithOptions (angular-nvd3.js:95)
    at Object.scope.api.refresh (angular-nvd3.js:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-nvd3.js:437)
    at Object.fn (angular-nvd3.js:505)
    at n.$digest (angular.js:15826)
    at n.$apply (angular.js:16097)
```

I've played with various chart options trying to get to anything that would render a chart, but all variations seem to indicate that `d3.scale` is `undefined` inside of `Object.nv` somewhere.   Yet, I'm just using the exact chart options and data from the `angular-nvd3` examples.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and how to get past this `d3.scale` being undefined when using `angular-nvd3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the NVD3 library you're using is based on V3.x of the D3 library, but you're using v4.x of the D3 library.  The ordinal scale API changed substantially between the two versions.

Change

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.1.1/d3.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>`

and that should fix the problem.

I also had some issues getting angular to work with Plunkr so I had to modify your example a little, but the core change comes down to the 1-liner.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bRAtP9xIiDaXnv04RAHu